# Use a slot-load drive with smaller disc

Tags: laptop, dvd, optical-drive, disc

I have a laptop with a slot-load (no tray) dvd drive, and a set of smaller discs from a dvd video camera I need to load.  What are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen some kind of plastic extension for smaller disks you just snap on. But where one would find these, I don't know.

[image]

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Memorex-3-Inch-DVD-Adapter-3-Pak/dp/B000M52EW0 came up from a quick search, though that particular product is out of stock there you should be able to find some somewhere. Make sure your drive's documentation says such adapters are supported. If the adapter unclips partly or fully in the drive and jams it up, you'll not get a repair under guarantee if they are not officially supported.

Comment: Amazingly, the local radio shack had one of these in stock.

Answer (score 2):

The safe option is to use a different drive, either an external drive or one on another computer.

Some slot-loading drives (e.g. the Wii) can handle smaller discs, and this should be in the laptop manual.