# Using those mini CDs in a MacBook Pro aluminium - is the media going to be "lost" inside the Mac?

Tags: mac, dvd, compact-disc

[image: Mini DVD image]

Can I use this on a MacBook Pro (aluminium unibody from 2010)?

Comment: +1 Good question. I looked at some photos, and it is one of those DVD drives that sucks in the media, right? I have never tried putting a min-cd in one of those.

Comment: I do not recommend it. I initially thought I could because the hardware I purchased was for a MacBook Pro, but it's software drivers were on a MiniCD. LAME!

Comment: @KCotreau: Exaclty. I have some blank here I found.

Comment: My initial thought was "I would not do it", so as the other guys said, who actually have tried, don't.

Comment: No, ...https://encrypted.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mini+cd+in+macbook+pro

Comment: Related: [MacBook doesn't recognize oddly shaped disk](http://superuser.com/questions/175307/macbook-doesnt-recognize-oddly-shaped-disk) and [Use a slot-load drive with smaller disc](http://superuser.com/questions/136407/use-a-slot-load-drive-with-smaller-disc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not recommend it. I've tried and failed at such a task. I ended up purchasing an external tray DVD drive.

You can also find 'brackets' that will convert the mini disc into a full size. Don't go down that road either.

Comment: short answer would be to use an external drive

Comment: @kobaltz: What you mean by "failed"? Did you lost the cd inside the mac?

Comment: Lost sort of implies not being able to find. I was able to find, but was no easy feat. I turned off the laptop and held it vertically. With a few gentle shakes, the MiniCD fell out. And if by gentle, I mean if my laptop were a child, I'd be in jail for abuse.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot.  From http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2801:

> The slot loading drives used in Apple portable computers work with only standard 120 mm round discs.

Comment: Also: Apple’s [HT2446: Using nonstandard or irregular sized discs in optical drives](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2446) (the now common internal, “slot loading” drives do not support non-standard shapes/sizes, but certain “flat carrier tray” drives do support them).